# AWS DataSync agent ran into an error connecting to AWS

Tags: aws-datasync

I'm trying to sync local S3 object storage to AWS S3 using AWS DataSync.
I configured agent and it shows as online in AWS DataSync dashboard under Agents tab.

This is screen of local datasync agent: [Agent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hchef.png)

Also it passes all of the network requirements from the agent: [Agent network checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNSvz.png)

When I start the task, it finished after 10 minutes, 5 seconds with error:

> DataSync agent ran into an error connecting to AWS. Please review the
> DataSync network requirements and ensure required endpoints are
> accessible from the agent. Please contact AWS support if the error
> persists.

Cloudwatch logs here:

```
2022-11-24T23:51:55.523+04:00   [INFO] Request to start task-07d3b5f3a2145f50c.

2022-11-24T23:54:15.550+04:00   [INFO] Execution exec-089b9bd72e66f49aa started.

2022-11-25T00:04:20.687+04:00   [INFO] Execution exec-089b9bd72e66f49aa finished with status Connection refused.
```

Please help to figure out the problem

Comment: Hello, have you solved the issue? We are running into the same issue which we have no clue on what went wrong. Thanks for helping